# Рисование произвольных фигур на графике OxyPlot с помощью готовой библиотеки WPF DrawTools

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

Добрый день, хочу совместить две готовые библиотеки, только не понятно как это можно сделать. Буду признателен за разного рода идеи.
Есть небольшая готовая реализация задуманного
[Репозиторий](https://A191919@bitbucket.org/A191919/drawtool.git)

Но возникает несколько проблем, как заставить наложенный Canvas прокручиватся вместе с графиком OxyPlot когда добавляются новые точки?
Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы действительно думаете, что всем не лень склонировать ваш репозиторий и разобраться в том, где же у вас проблема? Если бы вы сократили код до минимума и выложили здесь (реально только то, что необходимо, и ни байтом больше), ваш вопрос, вероятно, встретил бы больше симпатии.

Comment: Вопрос задавался неоднократно в разных формах, часто его минусовали с пометкой "ничего не понятно, мало информации". После этого я стал выкладывать ссылку на репозиторий.

Comment: Ну да, но теперь _слишком много_ информации. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve